# Combining filetype commands in vim?

Tags: vim, file-type

I'm using the example vimrc from the vim wiki, and "filetype indent plugin on" was in it. I'm wondering if that is the same as setting "filetype plugin on" and "filetype indent on", or do I have to turn on "filetype plugin" in a separate command?

Also is "filetype plugin indent on" the same as "filetype indent plugin on"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They can be provided separately:

```
filetype plugin on
filetype indent on
```

This is the same as the single line command: `filetype indent plugin on`, or `filetype plugin indent on`.

Either command, and `filetype indent plugin on` turn on filetype detection: `filetype on`.

`plugin` and `indent` are two separate `filetype` flags. Type just `:filetype` to see the individual state of the flags.

Comment: But is "filetype indent plugin on" the same as ("filetype plugin on" + "filetype indent on")?